# About const combined with reference and virtual inheritance

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
class A
{
    int x;
public:
    A(int i=25) { x=i; }
    int& f() const { return x; }
};

int main()
{
    A a(15);
    cout<<a.f();
    return 0;
}
```

I get an error saying that I can't initialize a reference of type **int&** from an expression of type **const int**? If I modify function's f() header, like "**int f() const**" or like "**int& f()**" it works. I know that a const function can't modify the members of the class, but in my example that's not happening and still is something wrong I can't understand.

Secondly, I have this piece of code:

```
class B { /* instructions */ };
class D1: virtual B { /* instructions */ };
class D2: virtual B { /* instructions */ };
class D3: B { /* instructions */ };
class D4: private B { /* instructions */ };
class D5: virtual public B { /* instructions */ };
class M1: D1, public D2, D3, private D4, virtual D5
{ /* instructions */ };
class M2: D1, D2, virtual D3, virtual D4, virtual D5
{ /* instructions */ };
```

The question is how many times is B inherited in M1 and and in M2. I think the answer is 3 (first from D1, then from D3 and then from D4) for both, but I'm not sure. Am I right?

Comment: You need to return a `const` reference, `const int&`.

Comment: You should also ask one question at a time. It might be better to make a different question out of the second part of this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're returning a reference to a member of your class. However, since you method is const, you're not allowed to return a non-const reference, because this would allow for the end user to modify your class state, after calling a const method.

Consider this:

```
class A
{
    int x;
public:
    A(int i=25) { x=i; }
    const int& f() const { return x; }
};

int main()
{
    A a(15);
    int &ref = const_cast<int &>(a.f());
    ref = 42;
    // a.x == 42
    return 0;
}
```

Using `const_cast` is generally a bad idea, it's here to demonstrate what could happen if you were allowed to return a non-const reference from a const method.

The end user could change the property `x` from your class, because of a call to a const function, which is not supposed to happen.

Returning the result by value is imo the way to go, since it's just an integer.

Answer (score 2):

First, your function may not be modifying a const value, but you're trying to return a const value as a non-const, which could then be modified.  The compiler is protecting you.  To keep it const, modify it as:

```
const int &f() const {... }
```

or

```
int f() const { .... }
```

The first returns a const reference, the second returns the result by-value.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question:

```
 class A
 {
    int x;
 public:
    A(int i=25) { x=i; }

    const int& f() const { return x; }
    //^^You should add const here
};

int main()
{
    A a(15);
    cout<<a.f();
    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise, you are returning non-const reference from a const member function. Another option is to simply return by value.

Answer (score 1):

In a non-static `const` member function, the type of `this` is changed to `A const *const`. Therefore it follows that the type of `x` is changed to `int const&`. A `const` object cannot be implicitly-converted to a non-const version of its type.

Answer (score 0):

`const int& f() const` is the way.

You're right, 3 times for both.